# Algorithm to compute average length of a simple path

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-hard

Given a connected graph and two nodes s and t, there can be many different simple paths (without cycles) from s to t.  Is there an efficient algorithm to find the average length of these paths?

Comment: Are you looking for exact algorithms or are you fine with approximations of the average length? By intuition, I would say that calculating the exact average length is NP-hard (seeing as checking if there exists a Hamiltonian path is already NP-hard), but approximating it to within $[(1-\varepsilon)L, (1+\varepsilon)L]$ (where L is the solution) might be possible efficiently.

Comment: @SmeltQuake Anything would be interesting. Can Hamiltonian circuit/path really be reduced to this problem? You can certainly determine if there is at least one path between s and t in poly time.

Comment: I do not know if Hamiltonian path can be reduced to this problem. This is just an intuition about why I think the exact problem is probably NP-hard: If you cannot even determine if there exists a path of length n, calculating the average over all lengths (which also sums over the paths of length n) is probably also hard.

Comment: @SmeltQuake I understood your intuition but the reduction, if it exists, is not clear to me. Hopefully someone here will see it more clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you already know that a polynomial algorithm for counting the number of simple paths between two nodes would imply P=NP, this result is due to Valiant (The complexity of enumeration and reliability problems, 1979).

Now imagine, expecting to discover a contradiction, that you could compute $\text{avg}(G, u, v)$ in polynomial time.

Let $G+l$ be the graph resulting from adding a simple path of length $l$ between $u$ and $v$ in $G$. This new path is made of $l-1$ new nodes and it does not interfere with any previous path from $u$ to $v$, provided $l \geq 2$.

Then, $\text{avg}(G+3,u,v) - \text{avg}(G+2,u,v)$ = $1/(\#\text{Paths}(G,u,v)+1)$, from which you can get $\#\text{Paths}(G,u,v)$ in polynomial time. But we know this cannot be expected to be done in polynomial time, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know a reference for the result of Valiant?

Comment: "The complexity of enumeration and reliability problems" L. Valiant 1979. There are free PDFs online, sorry I can't properly cite it, I won't have my computer with me today.